# Creating a large dask array backed by scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, dask

I have a function, call it `get_block(I, J)`, which takes two index sets, `I` and `J`, and returns a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` with entries taken from a *larger* sparse matrix. E.g., `get_block(I, J) == S[I, :][:, J]`, except that `S` is much too large to fit into memory.

I'd like to assemble a `dask.array` version of `S` using the function `get_block`, iterating over `(I, J)` pairs corresponding to dask chunks. I want to create an out-of-core version of `S` which I will be able to compute with despite it exceeding available memory. Dask is advertised as addressing this use case, so I thought I would give it a try.

It's not clear to me what the best way to do this is. I appear to be able to do things like this:

```
block1 = da.from_array(get_block(I, J1))
block2 = da.from_array(get_block(I, J2))
blocked = da.block([block1, block2])
```

Using this approach, I could loop over all `(I, J)` pairs and `da.block` the result together, but this doesn't strike me as a good way to go.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this? Is dask even the right choice?

Comment: A sparse matrix is not a subclass of `ndarray` so dask might not be able to handle it.

Comment: The data for a `csr` matrix is stored in 3 arrays, attributes of the matrix.  `data`, `indices`, and `indptr`.  The `scipy.sparse.save_npz` saves the matrix as a `npz` archive, one array per component `.npy` file.  See its code to see how they are saved and loaded.

Comment: I'm not having any trouble creating a dask array from a scipy sparse matrix. The dask docs claim to support sparse arrays: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-sparse.html. If I need to use the "sparse" library, go ahead and assume that that's OK---it isn't really relevant to my question.